Fail to run Flutter app on Android Simulator - don't understand log
I am trying to run an app on the Android simulator in Android Studio. It's running fine on the iOS simulator and I'm already running it on TestFlight. However, every time I try to run it on an Android simulator, I fail. I cannot even get to the start screen. In fact, I cannot even get it to print any of the debug messages I included, because the Console is full to the brim with other messages. It's a seemingly endless stream of the ever same messages, none of which is telling me anything. Here is an excerpt:
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvep.m(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvep.g(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):11)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at egur.B(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsAppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):9)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7754)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:7352)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:3668)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2542)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1213)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1117)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.k(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.l(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.e(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):4)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdn.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdk.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdp.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvep.m(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvep.g(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):11)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at egur.B(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsAppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):9)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7754)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:7352)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:3668)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2542)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1213)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1117)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.k(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.l(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.e(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):4)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdn.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdk.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdp.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvep.m(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvep.g(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):11)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at egur.B(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsAppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):9)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7754)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:7352)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:3668)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2542)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1213)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1117)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.k(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.l(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cmkx.e(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):4)
E/AndroidRuntime(17187):    at cvdn.a(:com.google.android.gms@231818047@23.18.18 (190800-535401451):0) 

I'm not even sure whether these are error messages or not, that's how little they are telling me. Btw. this is on Windows. I tried to run it on Windows after I failed on Mac.
This is one of the rare occasions where googling this yields zero results.
Can someone tell me what these messages mean and if and how I can stop them from spamming my console? Thanks!

Check if u have recently added new packages
then check all your packages on pub.dev and be sure that all  your packages are available for other platforms like Android, iOS, Windows and MacOS.
Like this:

Happy Codding :)

thanks for the hint. Sure I have added new packages. Basically all of them, since I have never been able to run an Android simulation yet. I checked all packages and they all support Android. Except for one, which just has an 'analysis issue' instead of a list of supported platforms. You think this is the problem?

Whats is that package?

it's chat_gpt_sdk

'Could not determine supported platforms as package resolution failed.' WTF is this package doesn't even provide supported platforms.  REMOVE IT!

hah.. yeah well... if only this wasn't the core functionality of my app...

Did you fix your bug yet?

Well I kinda got rid of the above stream of messages by just folding them (in Android Studio). I eventually got the app to run on Windows, but I there were so many steps in between that I cannot possibly tell you what I did. I'm sorry.
